# How to crop a face in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I want to be able to crop a face out of a picture in Photoshop.  The lasso tool seems to be difficult to use.  I remember there was another tool that allowed you to put different lines together one by one and then complete a circle but I don't remember the tool.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [the solution](http://www.xtro32.com/tutorials/face%20off/faceoff01.htm).

[image]

Edit: I assume you aren't trying to do the same, but the guide shows very clearly how to pull it off. And erasing the face would do the same.

Comment: +1 that's a very nice guide! Too bad it's got too many images to paste here.

Answer (score 4):

You might be thinking of the **Polygonal Lasso** tool

[image: Polygonal lasso]

If you right-click on the normal lasso tool, you'll see the option to lasso with the Polygonal Lasso or even the Magnetic Lasso.

With the Polygonal you will be able to click on various points of the image and create a larger, non-linear area for selection. You can then double-click on another point and have the last point joint up automatically with the first or come back again yourself on the origin point.

With the Magnetic, you gently guide the selection tool around the lines of your image and it will try and trace it best it can for you. The more contrast between the areas you're tracing, the better the tracking.